# Can I delete just my parenting.stackexchange account and leave all other SE accounts intact?

Tags: support, delete

I have seen [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/can-i-delete-my-account/7979#7979) about how to delete an account, but I am heavily invested in other sites on the SE network and would not want my other accounts to be effected.

If I delete my parenting account, will it delete all of my accounts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, deleting one account won't delete all of them. Obviously, don't go and put, "Please delete me" in the text of *all* your bios.

You could also just [disassociate your account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3735/how-to-dissociate-associated-accounts). Who knows? You may change your mind at some point...

Comment: Disassociating your accounts, now disassociates all your accounts across all sites.

Comment: @Jonathan: But then I think you can associate them again, with the exception of this one. Or?

Comment: No I don't think you can make an exception anymore. You might be able to dissassociation, add another open id to this site, and then delete the normal open id and reassocaite on another site.

Comment: @Jonathan: yes, you can - and yes, you do need to choose a different OpenID on the site you wish to disassociate. Please see the instructions in the post I linked to.

Comment: I just tried clicking disassociate and it did it on all the sites.

Comment: @Jonathan: the key here is that you're changing your credentials on *one* site, so that when you clear the associations the system won't rebuild them. So yeah, all your accounts will be disassociated, but they'll be *re*-associated when you log back in (or if you manually re-associate them)... With the exception of the one you changed the credentials on. I've updated that linked page to be more explicit about this.

Comment: @Shog9 - FYI: the linked question from your answer is 404-ing with "This question was removed from Meta Stack Exchange for reasons of moderation. Please refer to the help center for possible explanations why a question might be removed.".